# can not build rust project with llvm@13 on macos M1

Tags: rust, apple-m1, rust-cargo

I am developing a rust web project.

I am using argonautica v0.2.0 that uses llvm.  I changed my computer. I'm going with a macos using the M1 chipset. I installed llvm13 with brew. It gives an error when I say cargo build. I think it happened on my previous mac computer, but I couldn't find the solution this time. what should I do?

my new computer clang --version:

```
(base) burakdagli@Burak-MacBook-Pro ~ % clang --version
Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin21.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

my old computer clang --version (there is no error):

```
(base) burakdagli@BurakDagli-MacBook-Pro backend % clang --version
Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Error:

```
The following warnings were emitted during compilation:

warning: In file included from phc-winner-argon2/src/opt.c:26:
warning: In file included from phc-winner-argon2/src/blake2/blamka-round-opt.h:23:
warning: In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/emmintrin.h:13:
warning: In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/xmmintrin.h:13:
warning: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:50:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
warning:     return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_vec_init_v2si(__i, 0);
warning:            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
warning: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:129:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
warning:     return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_packsswb((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
warning:            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
warning: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:159:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
warning:     return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_packssdw((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
warning:            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
warning: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:189:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
warning:     return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_packuswb((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
warning:            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
warning: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:216:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
warning:     return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckhbw((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
warning:            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
warning: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:239:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
warning:     return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckhwd((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
warning:            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
warning: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:260:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
warning:     return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckhdq((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
warning:            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
warning: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:287:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
warning:     return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpcklbw((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
warning:            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
warning: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:310:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
warning:     return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpcklwd((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
warning:            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
warning: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:331:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
warning:     return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckldq((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
warning:            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
warning: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:352:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
warning:     return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddb((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
warning:            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
warning: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:373:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
warning:     return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddw((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
warning:            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
warning: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:394:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
warning:     return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddd((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
warning:            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
warning: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:416:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
warning:     return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddsb((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
warning:            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
warning: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:439:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
warning:     return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddsw((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
warning:            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
warning: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:461:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
warning:     return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddusb((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
warning:            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
warning: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:483:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
warning:     return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddusw((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
warning:            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
warning: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:504:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
warning:     return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_psubb((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
warning:            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
warning: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:525:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
warning:     return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_psubw((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
warning:            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
warning: fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
warning: 20 errors generated.

error: failed to run custom build command for `argonautica v0.2.0`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/Users/burakdagli/Desktop/wheelme/workspace/backend/target/debug/build/argonautica-b254c800add8ce34/build-script-build` (exit status: 1)
  --- stdout
  TARGET = Some("aarch64-apple-darwin")
  OPT_LEVEL = Some("0")
  HOST = Some("aarch64-apple-darwin")
  CC_aarch64-apple-darwin = None
  CC_aarch64_apple_darwin = None
  HOST_CC = None
  CC = None
  CFLAGS_aarch64-apple-darwin = None
  CFLAGS_aarch64_apple_darwin = None
  HOST_CFLAGS = None
  CFLAGS = None
  CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
  DEBUG = Some("true")
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = None
  CC_aarch64-apple-darwin = None
  CC_aarch64_apple_darwin = None
  HOST_CC = None
  CC = None
  CFLAGS_aarch64-apple-darwin = None
  CFLAGS_aarch64_apple_darwin = None
  HOST_CFLAGS = None
  CFLAGS = None
  CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = None
  CC_aarch64-apple-darwin = None
  CC_aarch64_apple_darwin = None
  HOST_CC = None
  CC = None
  CFLAGS_aarch64-apple-darwin = None
  CFLAGS_aarch64_apple_darwin = None
  HOST_CFLAGS = None
  CFLAGS = None
  CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = None
  CC_aarch64-apple-darwin = None
  CC_aarch64_apple_darwin = None
  HOST_CC = None
  CC = None
  CFLAGS_aarch64-apple-darwin = None
  CFLAGS_aarch64_apple_darwin = None
  HOST_CFLAGS = None
  CFLAGS = None
  CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = None
  CC_aarch64-apple-darwin = None
  CC_aarch64_apple_darwin = None
  HOST_CC = None
  CC = None
  CFLAGS_aarch64-apple-darwin = None
  CFLAGS_aarch64_apple_darwin = None
  HOST_CFLAGS = None
  CFLAGS = None
  CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = None
  running: "cc" "-O0" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-g" "-fno-omit-frame-pointer" "-arch" "arm64" "-I" "/var/folders/12/40djlr0j2b34zqj5k7_b72kr0000gn/T/argonautica.0e8KYDgOzE23" "-pthread" "-std=c89" "-g" "-o" "/Users/burakdagli/Desktop/wheelme/workspace/backend/target/debug/build/argonautica-bb74aac0caaa86b4/out/phc-winner-argon2/src/argon2.o" "-c" "phc-winner-argon2/src/argon2.c"
  running: "cc" "-O0" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-g" "-fno-omit-frame-pointer" "-arch" "arm64" "-I" "/var/folders/12/40djlr0j2b34zqj5k7_b72kr0000gn/T/argonautica.0e8KYDgOzE23" "-pthread" "-std=c89" "-g" "-o" "/Users/burakdagli/Desktop/wheelme/workspace/backend/target/debug/build/argonautica-bb74aac0caaa86b4/out/phc-winner-argon2/src/blake2/blake2b.o" "-c" "phc-winner-argon2/src/blake2/blake2b.c"
  running: "cc" "-O0" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-g" "-fno-omit-frame-pointer" "-arch" "arm64" "-I" "/var/folders/12/40djlr0j2b34zqj5k7_b72kr0000gn/T/argonautica.0e8KYDgOzE23" "-pthread" "-std=c89" "-g" "-o" "/Users/burakdagli/Desktop/wheelme/workspace/backend/target/debug/build/argonautica-bb74aac0caaa86b4/out/phc-winner-argon2/src/thread.o" "-c" "phc-winner-argon2/src/thread.c"
  running: "cc" "-O0" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-g" "-fno-omit-frame-pointer" "-arch" "arm64" "-I" "/var/folders/12/40djlr0j2b34zqj5k7_b72kr0000gn/T/argonautica.0e8KYDgOzE23" "-pthread" "-std=c89" "-g" "-o" "/Users/burakdagli/Desktop/wheelme/workspace/backend/target/debug/build/argonautica-bb74aac0caaa86b4/out/phc-winner-argon2/src/core.o" "-c" "phc-winner-argon2/src/core.c"
  running: "cc" "-O0" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-g" "-fno-omit-frame-pointer" "-arch" "arm64" "-I" "/var/folders/12/40djlr0j2b34zqj5k7_b72kr0000gn/T/argonautica.0e8KYDgOzE23" "-pthread" "-std=c89" "-g" "-o" "/Users/burakdagli/Desktop/wheelme/workspace/backend/target/debug/build/argonautica-bb74aac0caaa86b4/out/phc-winner-argon2/src/opt.o" "-c" "phc-winner-argon2/src/opt.c"
  running: "cc" "-O0" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-g" "-fno-omit-frame-pointer" "-arch" "arm64" "-I" "/var/folders/12/40djlr0j2b34zqj5k7_b72kr0000gn/T/argonautica.0e8KYDgOzE23" "-pthread" "-std=c89" "-g" "-o" "/Users/burakdagli/Desktop/wheelme/workspace/backend/target/debug/build/argonautica-bb74aac0caaa86b4/out/phc-winner-argon2/src/encoding.o" "-c" "phc-winner-argon2/src/encoding.c"
  cargo:warning=In file included from phc-winner-argon2/src/opt.c:26:
  cargo:warning=In file included from phc-winner-argon2/src/blake2/blamka-round-opt.h:23:
  cargo:warning=In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/emmintrin.h:13:
  cargo:warning=In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/xmmintrin.h:13:
  cargo:warning=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:50:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
  cargo:warning=    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_vec_init_v2si(__i, 0);
  cargo:warning=           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  cargo:warning=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:129:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
  cargo:warning=    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_packsswb((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
  cargo:warning=           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  cargo:warning=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:159:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
  cargo:warning=    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_packssdw((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
  cargo:warning=           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  cargo:warning=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:189:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
  cargo:warning=    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_packuswb((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
  cargo:warning=           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  cargo:warning=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:216:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
  cargo:warning=    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckhbw((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
  cargo:warning=           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  cargo:warning=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:239:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
  cargo:warning=    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckhwd((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
  cargo:warning=           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  cargo:warning=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:260:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
  cargo:warning=    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckhdq((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
  cargo:warning=           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  cargo:warning=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:287:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
  cargo:warning=    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpcklbw((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
  cargo:warning=           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  cargo:warning=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:310:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
  cargo:warning=    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpcklwd((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
  cargo:warning=           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  cargo:warning=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:331:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
  cargo:warning=    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_punpckldq((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
  cargo:warning=           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  cargo:warning=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:352:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
  cargo:warning=    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddb((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
  cargo:warning=           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  cargo:warning=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:373:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
  exit status: 0
  cargo:warning=    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddw((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
  cargo:warning=           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  cargo:warning=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:394:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
  cargo:warning=    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddd((__v2si)__m1, (__v2si)__m2);
  cargo:warning=           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  cargo:warning=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:416:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
  cargo:warning=    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddsb((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
  cargo:warning=           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  cargo:warning=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:439:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
  cargo:warning=    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddsw((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
  cargo:warning=           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  cargo:warning=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:461:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
  cargo:warning=    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddusb((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
  cargo:warning=           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  cargo:warning=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:483:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
  cargo:warning=    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_paddusw((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
  cargo:warning=           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  cargo:warning=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:504:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
  cargo:warning=    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_psubb((__v8qi)__m1, (__v8qi)__m2);
  cargo:warning=           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  cargo:warning=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/13.0.0/include/mmintrin.h:525:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
  cargo:warning=    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_psubw((__v4hi)__m1, (__v4hi)__m2);
  cargo:warning=           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  cargo:warning=fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
  cargo:warning=20 errors generated.
  exit status: 1
  exit status: 0
  exit status: 0
  exit status: 0
  exit status: 0

  --- stderr


  error occurred: Command "cc" "-O0" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-g" "-fno-omit-frame-pointer" "-arch" "arm64" "-I" "/var/folders/12/40djlr0j2b34zqj5k7_b72kr0000gn/T/argonautica.0e8KYDgOzE23" "-pthread" "-std=c89" "-g" "-o" "/Users/burakdagli/Desktop/wheelme/workspace/backend/target/debug/build/argonautica-bb74aac0caaa86b4/out/phc-winner-argon2/src/opt.o" "-c" "phc-winner-argon2/src/opt.c" with args "cc" did not execute successfully (status code exit status: 1).
```

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, `phc-winner-argon2/src/blake2/blamka-round-opt.h` unconditionally includes (and relies on) x86-only headers and features. So, you cannot compile it on ARM / AArch64

There is an open issue (https://github.com/P-H-C/phc-winner-argon2/issues/272) back from 2019 for ARM support.